# Get URL of Image dot navigation represents in Owl Carousel

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel

Trying to set up thumbnails for an owl carousel built in into a shopify theme. Found another solution than my own, but it would require too much tempering with a shopify theme.

My idea is to get an image url that dot navigation represent and set it as a background for the "dot".

Here is what I think it is going to look like

```
 $(".owl-page").each(function(){
 var newbg = (here is where I'm stuck)
 $(this).css('background-image','url(' + newbg + ')');
 });
```

Can anyone help with this one?

Comment: by `dot` u mean the span tag which is used for navigation?

Comment: which version of owl carousel you are using?

Comment: It came in min format with theme, but looks like the first one

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution.

```
$(".owl-page").each(function(){
    var newbg = $('.owl-item').eq($(this).data('owl-page')).find('img').attr('src')
     // Followed by your code. Now newbg will have the image url.
});
```

Comment: it does pull an image, but not the one associated with navigation item... p.s. thanks for helping on this one!

Comment: if the slider is having two pages, the first dot will have the index of first image in first slide and the second dot will have the index of first image in second slide. it would help if you can provide a demo for your slider.